# How to evaluate $\int_{\pi/6}^{\pi/3}\frac{\sqrt[3]{\sin x}}{\sqrt[3]{\sin x}+\sqrt[3]{\cos x}}$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

$$\int_{\pi/6}^{\pi/3} \frac {\sqrt[3]{\sin x}} {\sqrt[3]{\sin x} + \sqrt[3]{\cos x}}$$

I have tried it using transformation but its getting lengthy..it must be short question. please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint use $f (x)=f (a+b-x ) $ where a,b are lower ,upper limits . Then everything is straightforward

Answer (score 0):

Using the hint given by Archis Welankar:
$$\int_a^b f(x) dx=\int_a^bf(a+b-x)dx;\\
\int_{\pi/6}^{\pi/3} \frac {\sqrt[3]{\sin x}} {\sqrt[3]{\sin x} + \sqrt[3]{\cos x}}dx=\int_{\pi/6}^{\pi/3} \frac {\sqrt[3]{\sin (\pi/2-x)}} {\sqrt[3]{\sin (\pi/2-x)} + \sqrt[3]{\cos (\pi/2-x)}}dx \Rightarrow \\
\underbrace{\int_{\pi/6}^{\pi/3} \frac {\sqrt[3]{\sin x}} {\sqrt[3]{\sin x} + \sqrt[3]{\cos x}}dx}_{A}=\underbrace{\int_{\pi/6}^{\pi/3} \frac {\sqrt[3]{\cos x}} {\sqrt[3]{\cos x} + \sqrt[3]{\sin x}}dx}_{B} \Rightarrow \\
A-B=0.$$
Also:
$$\int_{\pi/6}^{\pi/3} \frac {\sqrt[3]{\sin x}} {\sqrt[3]{\sin x} + \sqrt[3]{\cos x}}dx=\int_{\pi/6}^{\pi/3} \frac {\sqrt[3]{\sin x}+\sqrt[3]{\cos x}-\sqrt[3]{\cos x}} {\sqrt[3]{\sin x} + \sqrt[3]{\cos x}}dx=\\
\int_{\pi/6}^{\pi/3} 1-\frac {\sqrt[3]{\cos x}} {\sqrt[3]{\cos x} + \sqrt[3]{\sin x}}dx \Rightarrow \\
A+B=\frac{\pi}{6}.$$
Hence:
$$A=\frac{\pi}{12}.$$